# sqlite connection string error in c++/cli

Tags: visual-c++

I'm using C++/cli Visual Studio 2010 and SQLite. The code compiles but the connection string is generating an error:

```
String ^ SQL = String::Format("INSERT INTO Backstroke   (Date, Fullname, Male, Group, Length, Points) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}' ) ", "a","b",true,"d","e",1);
cmdInsert->Connection = db;
cmdInsert->CommandText = SQL;
cmdInsert->ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get:

> error near "Group": syntax error and a comment about the connection string being incorrectly formed.

Male is a boolean field and the rest are text. Tried true, 1 and Yes for the male entry too all failing.

Comment: Don't put 'quotes' around values that are not strings.